# Jmeter - testing multiple urls in one Transaction controller and top 9 page's in another one

Tags: csv, jmeter

First I have a transaction controller with the top 9 pages inside.  That is working well.
But the transaction controller with browse a random page doesn't work.  I tried already different things but it keeps saying 100% error.
Can someone help?

This is my setup:
[image: Setup]

This is how i did setup the CSV data setup
[image: CSV data setup]

And this is what is in Browse random bouwdomein
[image: Random]

FYI in User Defined Variables is stated: BASE_URL_1 under Name
And in Value the URL (for example as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com))

Hope someone can help me to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your "different things" and "100% error" unfortunately don't tell anything to us, in order to be able to help we need to see:

1. At least first 2 lines of your `content.csv` file
2. [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) showing request and response details
3. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (preferably with [debug level logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) enabled)

Given your `content.csv` file:

1. exists in the given relative path
2. has valid [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and/or [DNS hostnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) of your "top 9 pages"  your configuration should work normally

Comment: First 2 lines of the content.csv file  
nl/bouwdomeinen/glaswerken/
nl/bouwdomeinen/schrijnwerken/

Comment: And the View Results Tree listener is saying:   Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:1970-01-01 01:00:00 CET
Load time:0
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:839
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:839
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Illegal character found in host: '/'


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Comment: I have no idea how to get the jmeter.log.file sorry.  I am a beginner with jmeter.

Comment: You cannot have `/` in the "Server Name or IP" field, it's not a valid character for the hostname, you need to put `${URL}` to "Path" section of the HTTP Request sampler

Comment: Dmitir, I have it now like you said. So only ${URL}  into Path section and nothing else in the HTTP Request sampler.  But still not working.

View results tree listener is giving me this:  Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Host may not be blank


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Request body is saying:  GET http:/nl/bouwdomeinen/glaswerken/

I see now that it is missing the base URL.  How can I add it?

Comment: Either base path to "Server name or IP" field or everything into the CSV file including the base path.